# Mask all objects less than given pixel count

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to remove all objects from my analysis that are less than a given size: in this case, less than 36 pixels. I had thought applying `image.gt(36)` would give me what I need, but when I use that to update the image, I don't see a different result.

How can I access the  object size to mask small objects?

```
// set the map to our region of interest
var pWestfield = ee.Geometry.Point([-72.87123222351073, 42.29052524043022]);
Map.setCenter(-72.87123222351073, 42.29052524043022, 13);

// get our dataset
var iGlobalSurfaceWater = ee.Image("JRC/GSW1_0/GlobalSurfaceWater");

// create a binary version of occurrence: did it or did it not?
var justOccurence = iGlobalSurfaceWater.select("occurrence");
var binary = justOccurence.and(justOccurence);
Map.addLayer(binary, {palette: 'FF0000'}, "Binary");

// Compute the number of pixels in each patch.
var patchsize = binary.connectedPixelCount(1024, false);
Map.addLayer(patchsize, {palette: ['000000', 'FFFFFF']}, 'patch size');

// Get rid of any patches that are less than 36 pixels.
// Theoretically.
var patchsizeLarge = patchsize.gt(36);
patchsizeLarge = patchsizeLarge.updateMask(patchsizeLarge);
Map.addLayer(patchsize, {palette: ['000000', 'FFFFFF']}, 'patch size large');
```

Comment: I am encountering a similar issue. Be aware that layers in google earth engine are sometimes not displayed in the correct way (depending on the scale, etc...).
So I had the same issue: I did not see any change when I was updating my data with the pixelsize mask. However, eventually there was a difference, which I noticed after exporting the data to my local machine and checking the results in Qgis.

Comment: Gorelick why is that when I increase the resolution of the image on GEE, it seems that connected pixels below the specified threshold gradually shows up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you simply have a typo in the last line of your script. You're displaying patchsize twice.  You want patchsizeLarge instead.

```
Map.addLayer(patchsizeLarge, {palette: ['000000', 'FFFFFF']}, 'patch size large');
```

Comment: Dear All,

I still don't quite understand the meaning of the "maxSize" parameter of the connectedPixelCount. What does it represent, or what is its meaning in the analysis?
Sincerely,
Philipe